# installing sqlite3 for python3.4.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

when I run ipython I get `WARNING: IPython History requires SQLite, your history will not be saved`. I have compled `python3.4.1` from source. Can anybody tell me how to install `sqlite3`. I have read somewhere that it should be included in the standard version of `python` after version 2.5, but apparently it is not. I think there is something I am not understanding.

I am on Linux, distro `Fedora 3.19.3`

Comment: What platform are you on? If Linux, what distribution?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to install the SQLite development headers. Without those, the Python installation process cannot compile the `sqlite3` extension.

On Fedora, those headers are packaged up as `sqlite-devel`.

You probably want to get other C extensions compiled as well; you want the following packages when compiling Python from source:

```
zlib-devel
bzip2-devel
readline-devel
sqlite-devel
openssl-devel
ncurses-devel
tk-devel
gdbm-devel
db4-devel
libpcap-devel
xz-devel
expat-devel
```

Once installed, re-compile Python (`configure; make; make install`).

Comment: I think those headers are already installed somewhere, but they are not in the path. How can I find their location?

Comment: @simona: Python knows how to find them; if it didn't they were not installed.